# How to remove focus from a Tk() element in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, focus, focusout

In Python 3, can you prevent focus from a root-level Tk() element when clicked?
After unfocusing, focus must be returned to the previous window that had focus.

Comment: You can call [`focus_force()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) on the previous window (from a bound event-handler function).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to switch focus between two tkinter windows:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

first = Tk ()
second = Tk ()

first.title ('First Window')
b1 = Button (first, text = 'Goto Second Window')
b1.config (command = second.focus_force)
b1.pack ()

second.title ('Second Window')
b2 = Button (second, text = 'Goto First Window')
b2.config (command = first.focus_force)
b2.pack ()

first.mainloop ()
```